# How to export multiple tables in one file

Tags: mysql

I'd like to export a backup file of some tables in just a single file and make it loadable when imported back.

```
    SELECT * FROM survey_tbl 
    UNION SELECT * FROM answer_tbl 
    UNION SELECT * FROM question_tbl 
    UNION SELECT * FROM dependent_question_tbl 
    UNION SELECT * FROM nest_answer_tbl 
    UNION SELECT * FROM nest_question_tbl 
    INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile'
```

I got an error in the union select because they have different columns,
Any help is well appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Below is the code that works in a single table and file

```
    SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";
```

Comment: Even if the tables had the same number and types of columns, what use would your backup file be to recreate the tables?  How would you would deal with such a tangled mess? (not my downvote).

Comment: You may need other tools, or you should have a custom converter, to convert your data into text and import them back.  No quick way for this.

Comment: You should use `mysqldump` for exporting multiple tables.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, Thanks it's really helpful.

Comment: I'll post as an answer so we can get this question wrapped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `mysqldump` for exporting multiple tables.

This tool comes with every installation of MySQL, and it's easy to use.

It has a bunch of options. Read the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

Of particular interest is the option `mysqldump --tab` which basically uses `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` just like you were doing, so it output data as flat files instead of SQL scripts. These files can be loaded quickly with `mysqlimport`.

Comment: it's really great, I know i have so much to learn, Thanks for the link.